# GEOS C API - calculating areas with WGS84 coords (SRID=4326)

Tags: wgs84, geos

I create a polygon where each x/y point is WGS84 format
lat/long values.

The polygons are good approximations to circles and sectors of
radius R (each circumference/arc point is a projected lat/long
value of distance R from a centre/apex coordinate - which I have
verified is correct by computing the Haversine distance between
the edge and reference points and getting a value of R back) .

I use GEOSSetSRID(4326) to indicate the coords are WGS84 format.
GEOSGetSRID() confirms the SRID is set.

Use of GEOSArea then gives a value not even remotely close to
the expected value.

I do not see what else I can programmatically do.

If I set the points in cartesian format, and then set the SRID to
4326, will GEOS implicitly convert the polygon points to WGS84 ??

Is the basic GEOS C API incapable of doing the above ??
Dos SRID have no meaning to the API at all ??

Any info/pointers to correct usage/solutions would be much appreciated.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

The distance that is given is something like degrees between the two points. In actuality, the GEOS API (at least the C++ interface) is units agnostic; the units it gives the distance in is based on whatever you passed in.

In general, multiplying the result you get by 111000 gives you a fairly accurate measurement in meters. For area, you have to do 111000^2.